# Any Alternate to given if-else statement

Tags: math

I have very simple requirement. Currently in my program I am doing something like this.

```
int low=getLowValue();

if(low==20)
   low=15;
else
   low=(low/5)*5;  // here '/' is for integer division
```

Is there any simple way to do this? Any one line statement which fulfill above condition(not ternary operator).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You realize that `(low/5)*5` is basically `low`.

Comment: Nope for low=13 it will become 10

Comment: low == 20 ? low = 15 : low=(low/5)*5;

Comment: That means you're using a language that uses `/` for integer division, in which case only, `low` isn't necessarily `(low/5)*5`.

Comment: So that's peusocode. What kind of division should that be? And what's wrong with this if-else? **Edit:** your edit does not help!

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a ternary operation is usually ideal for this sort of thing.

But, since you state you don't want that, you can also do it in "one"<sup>(a)</sup> line by providing your own function to do the heavy lifting:

```
int GetLowValueWithPreCheck(int checkFrom, int checkTo) {
    int val = getLowValue();
    if (val == checkFrom) return checkTo;
    return (val / 5) * 5;
}

int low = getLowValueWithPreCheck(20, 15);
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Quoted since it refers to one line at the point of call - this is usually a good thing to do if you're going to be doing the operation in many places and want to minimise the code clutter.

Comment: Upvote just for ```a ternary operation is ideal for this sort of thing```.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is readable and I would not change it. But if you really want, you can do this (in C++ at least):

```
low = (low - (low == 20)) / 5 * 5;
```

If `low == 20` this results in `(20 - 1) / 5 * 5` which evaluates to `15`.
If `low != 20` this results in `low / 5 * 5`.

Comment: `low - (low == 20)` won’t work in a language with strict typing.

Answer (score -3):

The given code snippet is written following **Java** syntaxes to solve the required problem.

```
low = (low==20)?15:low;
```